# Making a script output CSV friendly

Tags: bash, scripting

I've made a little script to extract the MD5Sum Hashes for each file in a users downloads directory.

I want to make the output CSV friendly by placing a , in between each MD5 hash, and the name of the file.

Current Output:

```
d35e918d05c615b430e055d06ad09e8f  JavaSetup_1376232357.exe
d35e918d05c615b430e055d06ad09e8f  JavaSetup_1848597537.exe
feca515ae90edd11e0dad95f0c123acc  javaSetup.exe
```

Desired Output:

```
d35e918d05c615b430e055d06ad09e8f,JavaSetup_1376232357.exe
d35e918d05c615b430e055d06ad09e8f,JavaSetup_1848597537.exe
feca515ae90edd11e0dad95f0c123acc,javaSetup.exe
```

Current script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /home/$USER/Downloads/
for file in *; do
    md5sum "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to substitute the two spaces for a comma:

```
   ...
done | sed 's/  /,/'
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Do you know if there is a way I can re-order the output. Right now, it's outputting md5hash -> filename, is there a way I can force filename -> md5hash? Would this be done using something like AWK?

Comment: Sure, for nothing strange (ex. filenames with spaces), you can just `awk '{print $2,$1}'`